# Django: Submit Multiple of Same Forms with One Button

Tags: python, django, forms

I want to improve my page by having one Submit button at the bottom of multiple forms to submit the data to SQL. At the moment, each form has its own submit button and when click on one, it submits all of them at once. I went through different posts and none talked about multiple forms that were all the same.

I have one form that consists of Value and Name. I populate a table with this form depending on how many different Name fields there are.

[image]

In the View, I populate the form as a list containing different instances for each Name. Then in the Template I loop through each item in the form and display it on a row.

**VIEW**

```
for enumeration in enumerationidlist:  
    enumerationdata=Enumeration.objects.get(enumerationid=enumeration)  

    if request.method == 'POST':  
        form = form + [[EditEnumerationForm(request.POST, instance=enumerationdata, read=read, prefix=i),enumerationdata.enumerationid]]

        if form[i][0].is_valid():  
            form[i][0].save(commit=True)

        else:  
            print(form[i][0].errors)

    else: 
        form = form + [[EditEnumerationForm(instance=enumerationdata, read=read, prefix=i), enumerationdata.enumerationid]]
        initialList.append(enumerationdata)   
    i = i + 1
```

**Template**

```
<tbody>
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% for form in forms %}
    <tr>
      <td>
        {% crispy form.0 %}
      </td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

How can I have just one Submit button displayed to the user that can submit (all at once) the forms? I tried adding an input with a form tag around it, but it does not work because the data on the forms are not passed through the POST.

This fails because the submit button is not under the original form tag.

```
<form method='POST' action=''>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class = "col-xs-12">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name= "firstSubmit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can use just 1 form to submit all the data. Only things you have to create array of input type="text" For Example:- <input type='text' name='data[]' />

Comment: @Lavanya , I am using 1 form, just displaying it over and over. I do not think I follow you. Do you suggest to use one form that will repeat its fields over and over (through an array)?

Comment: The documentation covers this in detail: [model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets).

Comment: @Daniel.... ha I did not wanted to look into formsets but I guess I will have to. Thanks.

Comment: Formsets are really cool! Dont hesitate to use them. Here a nice library that would help you using them: https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms

Comment: @Below the Radar, thank you very much! I will learn everything there is about formsets